# Browser can't find localhost while Apache and MySQL are up and running

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I have reinstalled my Xampp Application, Apache is running on port 443 and 8080, MySQL is running on 3306.

If I go to Localhost, it still gives me a 404 Error while it should give me a message like "You have succesfully installed Xampp!"

What can be the problem?

Comment: which operating system you are using..??

Comment: Did you try http://localhost:8080?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you omit the port, http uses port 80 by default and port 443 for https.

So try to call

```
http://localhost:8080
```

or

```
https://localhost
```

If this does not help you should check the accesslog of your webserver.